# Aggregating pixel size with Raster package in R

Tags: raster, r-raster

I have a raster of where pixel sizes are approximately 0.04 meters and would like to aggregate them to a resolution of 5 meters using the `raster` package. I'm curious if there is an equation for determining the `fun=` argument in `raster`?

Comment: It is `5 / 0.04 = 125`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.